# What happens with static function returning string array Visual C#?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have static function which returns array of strings. I call this function from the loop and store return value into temporary array. 
My question is would GC clean up this in first generation or would it stay and hang around as generation 2.

Below you can see code snippet.

-----------UPDATED CODE----------------------------

Thank you for all the reply.
Let's say I will have something like this would this clean up string arrays?

```
    public static string[] SplitString(string strLine_)
    {
        string[] bit_ = strLine_.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return bit_;
    }
```

//------inside different function--------------//

```
   private void Foo()
   {
       while (numOfVolElts > count)
       {
           line = sr_.ReadLine();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                string[] bit4 = Definitions.SplitString(line);
                for (int j = 0; j < bit4.Length; j++)
                {
                    int matNum = Convert.ToInt32(bit4[j]);
                    volElements[count].matnr = matNum;
                    count++;

                    if (matNum > numMaterials)
             numMaterials = matNum;
        } 
   }
    }
    //GC.Collect(); //I know it's not recommended to call GC manually //but for this   testing purpose to check if it cleans up string //array.
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can state deterministically what generation an object will end up in... it depends on when the GC does its cleanup runs and whether the object is still in scope at that time.

Comment: The loop doesn't allocate anything so this array is very unlikely to survive beyond gen#0.  Do *not* call GC.Collect().  And in fact never fret about the GC until you have positive proof that you have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is would GC clean up this in first generation or would it stay and hang around as generation 2.

Note the generations here are Gen0 and Gen1, your strings will never make it to Gen2.

Both could happen. When a GC happens during that while-loop, some of the strings would be in use (reachable) and promote from Gen0 to Gen1. But with a low probability and never more than a handful.

So nothing to worry about here.

Comment: Unless of course the string is big enough that the resulting array goes straight to LOH.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - I think we can exlude that.

Comment: Yes line is not very big but loop itself is big. Meaning there are many lines but lines are short

Comment: Again: nothing to worry about. All your (arrays of) strings are shortlived. The call to `GC.Collect();` is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the array is quite short lived, it's likely that almost every instance will stay in generation 1.

There are no guarantees that no instances won't make it to generation 2, that depends on when the garbage collections happen and what else is going on. That should however be sufficiently rare.

Comment: Can you share any metrics or heuristics to back up the assertion "that should be sufficiently rare" or is that just based on the fact that the instances are in scope for such a short period of time and the GC runs will be relatively sparse?

Comment: @AntP: Yes, it's based on the short time, and that the code doesn't have anything that would cause a lot of collections. The instances are only in use one at a time (remember that scope is irrelevant for garbage collection), so only one instance could be caught in use when a collection happens, which limits the risk.

Comment: What if I call garbage collector right after the loop?

Comment: @user2015971 Why would you do that?

Comment: To see if it memory would get cleaned up at all. I am not sure how to call GC for generation 1 only

Comment: @user2015971 Again, why? Trust it to do its job and worry about your own code.

Comment: @user2015971: If you call `GC.Collect` after the loop, it will just cause a collection even if one isn't needed. Having some uncollected garbage doesn't normally impact performance, but causing collections will always impact the performance.